# How to prevent react being refresh after receiving response from server side when form being submitted

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Am having issues with reactjs and nodejs, I want to upload image and at the same time save user input into database. I was able to accomplish all these but the problem is if I completely fill the form and hit submit button data will successfully submitted but react page is refreshing and I user `e.preventDefault()` and  `e.stopPropagation()` function all still same thing and also I wrap my `___handleSubmit()` but `onClick={ (e) => { this.___handleSubmit(e)}}` and all still same thing.

**React Code**

```
  __handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("collection_title", this.state.collection_title);
formData.append("collection_description",this.state.collection_description);
formData.append("quiz_category", this.state.quiz_category);
formData.append("visibility", this.state.visibility);
formData.append("selectedCover", this.state.selectedCover);
formData.append("User_ID", this.state.user_data.User_ID);

quiz.createQuizCollection(formData, CollectionResponse => {
  if (CollectionResponse)
    if (CollectionResponse && CollectionResponse[0].error) {
      toast.error(`Message: ${CollectionResponse[0].message}`);
    } else {
      toast.success(`Message: ${CollectionResponse[0].message}`);
      this.setState({ Collection_ID: CollectionResponse[0].Collection_ID });
      this.props.history.push(`/create/${CollectionResponse[0].Collection_ID}`);
    }
});
```

};

**Node Code**

```
app.post("/api/create-collection", (req, res) => {

       if (req.files === null) {
       const col_res = {
         message: "Collection cover image can not be empty, Please Upload Cover Image",
         error: true,
         collectionStatus: false,
         nums_row: 0,
         Collection_ID: ''
       };
       return res.status(200).json({ Response: col_res }, 500, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
   } else {

        const selectedImage = req.files.selectedCover;
        const collection_title_slug = dataValidation.convertToSlug(req.body.collection_title);
        const collection_path = __dirname+"/../client/public/images/"+collection_title_slug;

        if (!fs.existsSync(collection_path)){
            fs.mkdirSync(collection_path);
        } 
        selectedImage.mv(`${collection_path}/${selectedImage.name}`,err => {
            if (err) {
                const col_res = {
                    message: "Unable to upload image, Please Try Again",
                    error: true,
                    collectionStatus: false,
                    nums_row: 0,
                    Collection_ID: ""
                };
                return res.status(200).json( { Response: col_res }, 500, "Content-Type", "application/json" );
            } else {
                CollectionModel.CreateCollection(selectedImage.name, req.body, result => {
                    if (!result.error) {
                        return res.status(200).json({ Response: result }, 200, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    } else {
                        return res.status(200).json({ Response: result }, 300, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
   }
});
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The `setState` call is likely causing the refresh. Why do you need to store the collection id in local state?

Comment: I don't think so cause if I comment out the callback response it still refresh

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.history.push` is the reason.

> `history.push` is used to change the current location

Comment: Am not sure if it's push cause if I comment out the callback response it still refresh